# How to force ISO-8859-1 encoding for form data using LWP::UserAgent?

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent, percent-encoding

It seems that LWP::UserAgent always encodes form data as UTF-8, even if explicitely encode it as ISO-8859-1 as follows:

```
use Encode;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use utf8;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->post('http://localhost:8080/', {
    text => encode("iso-8859-1", 'è'),
});
```

Request content is `text=%C3%A8`. How can I have `è` encoded as `%E8` instead?

Comment: How did you determine the request content? Network sniffer definitely says `text=%E8`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rM3xS.png

Comment: Interesting. I'm running `nc` on port 8080, and I get `text=%C3%A8`. Specs: MacOS X 10.6, perl v5.10.0, libwww-perl/5.837.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer to myself:** just put the variable name (i.e. "text") in quotes instead of writing it as a bareword.

```
$ua->post('http://localhost:8080/', {
    'text' => encode("iso-8859-1", 'è'),
});
```

**Ratio**: this weird behaviour is caused by the combination of the following factors:

- [Perl bug #68812](http://rt.perl.org/rt3/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=68812) caused the UTF-8 internal flag to be set to all barewords. This was fixed in latest Perl versions (>= 5.12);
- URI.pm concatenates keys to values (i.e. "text=è") before converting characters, so the value is always promoted to UTF-8 if the key has the internal flag set, even if you passed the value as octects.

I don't think that the bug pointed out by @Lumi about URI.pm using `\C` has effect on this specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

Hehe. :-) This has to do with the incrementally growing support for Unicode in the last dozen of Perl releases and the regex feature `\C` used by the [`URI` module](http://p3rl.org/URI), to be more precise, by `URI::Escape`. Read [this thread on perl-unicode from 2010 (Don't use the \C escape in regexes - Why not?)](http://code.activestate.com/lists/perl-unicode/3181/) to understand the background.

Why the `URI` module? Because it is used to do form and URL encoding by `HTTP::Request::Common`.

Meanwhile, here's a script I wrote to remind myself of how tricky this issue is, especially as the `URI` module is such a frequently used one:

```
use 5.010;
use utf8;
# Perl and URI.pm might behave differently when you encode your script in
# Latin1 and drop the utf8 pragma.
use Encode;
use URI;
use Test::More;
use constant C3A8 => 'text=%C3%A8';
use constant   E8 => 'text=%E8';
diag "Perl $^V";
diag "URI.pm $URI::VERSION";
my $chars = 'è';
my $octets = encode 'iso-8859-1', $chars;
my $uri = URI->new('http:');

$uri->query_form( text => $chars );
is $uri->query, C3A8, C3A8;

my @exp;
given ( "$^V $URI::VERSION" ) {
        when ( 'v5.12.3 1.56' ) { @exp = (   E8, C3A8 ) }
        when ( 'v5.10.1 1.54' ) { @exp = ( C3A8, C3A8 ) }
        when ( 'v5.10.1 1.58' ) { @exp = ( C3A8, C3A8 ) }
        default                 { die 'not tested :-)' }
}

$uri->query_form( text => $octets );
is $uri->query, $exp[0], $exp[0];

utf8::upgrade $octets;
$uri->query_form( text => $octets );
is $uri->query, $exp[1], $exp[1];

done_testing;
```

So what I get (on Windows and Cygwin) is:

```
C:\Windows\system32 :: perl \Opt\Cygwin\tmp\uri.pl
# Perl v5.12.3
# URI.pm 1.56
ok 1 - text=%C3%A8
ok 2 - text=%E8
ok 3 - text=%C3%A8
1..3
```

And:

```
MiLu@Dago: ~/comp > perl /tmp/uri.pl
# Perl v5.10.1
# URI.pm 1.54
ok 1 - text=%C3%A8
ok 2 - text=%C3%A8
ok 3 - text=%C3%A8
1..3
```

**UPDATE**

You can handcraft the request body:

```
use utf8;
use Encode;
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $chars = 'ölè';
my $octets = encode( 'iso-8859-1', $chars );
my $body = 'text=' .
        join '',
        map { $o = ord $_; $o < 128 ? $_ : sprintf '%%%X', $o }
        split //, $octets;
my $uri = 'http://localhost:8080/';
my $req = HTTP::Request->new( POST => $uri, [], $body );
print $req->as_string;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $rsp = $ua->request( $req );
print $rsp->as_string;
```

Comment: Good catch, Lumi. That's something ugly ugly ugly. Upgrading URI.pm to 1.58 didn't fix the issue; it seems that I need Perl 5.12 for that work out of the box. So, back to my question, is building the `HTTP::Request` manually the only portable way to achieve `%E8`?

Comment: I don't know but I would pursue that road as it is easy enough. I updated my answer to include the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;  # Script is encoded using UTF-8.

use Encode                qw( encode );
use HTTP::Request::Common qw( POST );  # This is what ->post uses

my $req = POST('http://localhost:8080/', {
    text => encode("iso-8859-1", 'è'),
});

print($req->as_string());
```

gives

```
POST http://localhost:8080/
Content-Length: 8
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

text=%E8
```

Are you use you are passing «è» and not its UTF-8 encoding? If I use its UTF-8 encoding, I get the same result as you.

```
...
my $req = POST('http://localhost:8080/', {
    text => encode("iso-8859-1", encode("UTF-8", 'è')),
});
...
```

gives

```
POST http://localhost:8080/
Content-Length: 11
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

text=%C3%A8
```